# Finding the sum of the components of a series.

Tags: sequences-and-series

I was reading sequence and series and there I saw the formula for the sum of the squares of the natural numbers ($1^2+2^2+3^2+\cdots+n^2$) so I just incurred a doubt about the sum obtained when these squared numbers are inversed i.e $$\frac{1}{1^2}+\frac{1}{2^2}+\frac{1}{3^2}+\cdots+\frac{1}{n^2}$$
I tried a lot but did not reach a conclusion. I tried to convert the whole sum of the components into a single fraction, tried to take commons etc. but did not succeed. So is there a way to find a general form for the sum ? If yes please help me out. Any help is appreciated. $$Thank you$$

Comment: This is a [generalized harmonic number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number#Generalized_harmonic_numbers). I don't think there is a known closed form for the finite sum, but it's [well known](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basel_problem) that in the limit, $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^2} = \pi^2/6$

Answer (score 0):

If you take common denominator it should be this
$$\frac{\sum_i \prod_{j\neq i} j^2}{\prod_i i^2}$$
It is not the simplest possible BUT it is workable. Albeit not terribly pretty.